# ORA-00904 Error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm using JDBC to access a database and I'm basically querying by calling a String.

Here is my table `book_table`:

```
| title | book no. | author_first | author_last |

The cat, 0, Tim, Joe
The dog, 1, John, Soe
The mouse, 2, Josh, Moe
```

And here is the SQL statement I am querying with:

```
"select title from book_table where author_first like '%tim%' and author_last like '%joe%'";
```

I keep getting the error exception in Java: `ORA-00904: "author_last": invalid identifier"`

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but then again I can't see your Java code.  Please include it.

Comment: did you run your query in some AP(TOAD,SQL Dev, etc.etc.)

Comment: show your java code too

Comment: **[Edit]** your question and add the **exact** `create table` statement for the table `book_table`. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be very likely that you may have used double quotes while creating the DDL for the book_table.

From the error it means that there is no such column as *author_first*

The names used in database should be working fine and that uppercase and lowercase could be very well be ignored if you would have not used double quotes.

```
 create table book_table(title varchar2(100)); 
 create table BOOK_TABLE(TITLE varchar2(100));
```

In both the cases

```
  select * from book_table where title like '%mytitle%';
```

should be working fine.

However if you would have used double quotes, then you would have to use the exact cases while performing sql operations.

```
create table "BOOK_TABLE"("Title" varchar2(100));
```

In this case

```
select * from book_table where title like '%mytitle%'
```

would not work

You have to make use of

```
select * from book_table where "Title" like '%mytitle%';
```

I'd suggest dropping the table and recreating them without double quotes and see if that solves it.